# How do I specify resulting permissions of openshift origin secret files?

Tags: mongodb, openshift, kubernetes, openshift-origin

I'd like to know if there is a way to specify permissions for files defined in a [Secret](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/secrets.html).
For instance, we defined a keyfile for mongodb and we want it to have permissions as specified in a [manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/enable-internal-authentication/) - 600, is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not currently possible. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4789 is open to improve control over how Secret data is mounted into a container.